# Deserialize json into entity object without use entity

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization

I need to deserialize several json files, one json file per table in the database.

In my process, I need to generalize the method. So I don't want to have to declare each class of the entity when doing the deserialize.

```
public function readJsonFile(string $fileName, string $tableName)
    {
        $file = $this->projectDir . '/var/json-database/extranet_table_' . $fileName . '.json';
        $fileString = file_get_contents($file);
        $fileObj = json_decode($fileString, true);

        return $this->convertJsonToObject($fileObj['data'], $fileName, $tableName);
    }

    private function convertJsonToObject(array $arrayData, string $fileName, string $tableName)
    {
        $arrayTableObj = [];
        foreach ($arrayData as $data) {
            $data['id'] = intval($data['id']);
            (isset($data['active'])) ? $data['active'] = true : $data['active'] = false;

            $dataJson = json_encode($data);
            $dataObj = $this->serializer->deserialize($dataJson, $tableName, 'json');

            $arrayTableObj[] = $dataObj;
        }

        dd($arrayTableObj);
    }
```

Currently $tableName === 'Language'.
I can't do $tableName::class, I get this error

> Cannot use "::class" on value of type string

I am looking for a way to pass the class where the name is in $tableName without having to instantiate it

Comment: Are your entities in the same namespace? Calling `::class` will return the FQCN as a string, just like if you did `'App\Entity\'.$tableName`.

Comment: Thank you, it works by putting directly the path 'App\Entity\'.$tableName :)